# User cannot run C# released app - "The application failed to init.properly"

Tags: c#, build-process, release

I am desperate due to this problem:
I have created and built app which works fine on mine and my colleagues PC. However, third user reports that with .NET 3.5 the app reports:
"The application failed to init.properly" and with .NET 4.0 "Unable to find the version of runtime to run this application“.
Could you please advice? It was built with 3.5.
**EDIT:After installing 3.5 SP2, there is no error message. It just does not execute :(**
Thanks

Comment: Please give more information - Check the offending PC's windows event logs and put up here any information found.

Comment: That isn't a .NET problem.  That is a "user's computer is a POS and needs to be wiped clean" problem.

Comment: This message displays an error code after the text, similar to 0xc0000005.  We need to know that code.

Comment: Petr, check if you target 3.5 or 3.5SP1

Comment: The error code ends with 0135. I have asked for their SP, no response yet.

Answer (score 2):

For .NET 4.0 version problem is that the framework is not installed on the users PC.
For .NET 3.5 if you are sure that the needed version of framework installed then most probably user doesn't have access to some system file required by the application.